# Jerky animation on window open/close

Tags: windows-7

Today, I received and installed Windows 7, and one of the first (slightly) annoying things I noticed is a visible jerk when opening of closing new windows. When I minimize or maximize already running window, the animation is smooth from beginning to end, but when I start a new program, it seems that just at the end of the animation Windows thinks for a fraction of a second. It is a bit distracting; especially since Windows 7 seems to be overall more responsive than Windows Vista. Does anybody has the same experience? Could it, for instance, a 64bit version specific issue (just in case)? I upgraded Vidia drivers, and even though my video card is not capable running latest games, it should be able to handle this (since it was OK in Vista, and since it does not look like a video issue).

Comment: What CPU and memory do you have installed?

Comment: What ChrisF said, with the addition of what GPU/Graphics card do you have?

Comment: E6750 (Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.66GHz)

Comment: Video card: nVidia 8600 GT

Comment: Maybe it's just me - I tend to notice such things. Maybe it is intentional, but it will take me some time to get used to it. I may try the 32bit version tomorrow.

Comment: Also memory: 4GB.

Comment: If your memory is more than 3GB, don't bother with the 32-bit version.  It's not worth losing a GB of usable RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Is this the animation stutter you are referring to? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWdVrSUhvLE&NR=1

This is a well known problem (I'm not sure if its a bug or a "feature") in Windows 7.  For some reason or another Microsoft just changed the aero animation for opening and closing windows - I suspect that they wanted it to be more apparent to users when the animation was finished and they could start using the window.  It bugs me too, but I have not found any way to revert it back to the vista-style animations.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same exact thing and it is very annoying.  Have same processor as you but nVidia 9800M GS.  Windows rates aero perfomance at 6.7 but the windows jerking on open/close really annoys me for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here. I have a 6.9 graphics score but to me it seems like the jerky animation is on purpose. It also happens when I close a window (first a little hiccup, then it disappears smoothly).
Annoying!